# Css adding subclass to a h4

Tags: css, class

I have a h4 title, when it's chosen i want to change it's background color. I've tried following css but it didnt work. Where is wrong part?

```
.sub_topic h4 {
  margin:0 0 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  width:120px;   
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #4e7ac7;
  border: 3px solid #4e7ac7;    
  height:20px;
}

.sub_topic h4 .chosen {
  background-color: #a0be29;
  border: 3px solid #a0be29;
}
```

I also tried only `.chosen` and then adding it to `<h4>` but it didn't work.

Comment: when you mean add do you mean h4 + .chosen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
h4.chosen
```

instead of

```
h4 .chosen
```

Comment: yes that works, thanks a lot. i cant accept answer now lol. i will do it in 10 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Try `h4.chosen` instead of `h4 .chosen`

All of your CSS attributes look okay.

Comment: actually the `.subtopic h4` is a valid (if odd) selector syntax ... an `h4` that is a descendant of an element with class `.subtopic`